# How to clock Nvidia gpu to specific performance level?

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I have Switchable graphics AMD and Nvidia GPU. I use only Nvidia graphics.

I saw performance levels on Powermizer settings of Nvidia X Server Settings.

My question is, is there any way to force lock gpu to specific performance level?

For example. When on batter 0, on AC 3.

I googled and tried some tweaks like creating conf files or modifying xorg.conf. But still i see my gpu switches to 2 or 3 performance level on battery.